# Null reference exception in property setter

Tags: c#, properties, set, nullreferenceexception

I have a class with several string fields.
This class represents a model for a serialization, so I have to check the length of its fields.

I do so with

```
public String Address {
        get { return this.address; }
        set {
              if (value.Length > 15)
              {
                this.address= value.Substring(0,15);
              }
               else { this.address = value; }
            }
    }
```

All previous properties are being successfully set, but at certain point I get an error
of 'null reference exception'.

I would avoid a solution like

```
public String Address {
        get { return this.address; }
        set {
             if(value!=null){ 
             if (value.Length > 15)
              {
                this.address= value.Substring(0,15);
              }
               else { this.address = value; }
            }
          }
    }
```

What do you suggest?

Comment: In order to *prevent* an NRE you surely have to *check* for null. What´s your problem on doing so?

Comment: I do not understand why? why works for previous field (city,region...) and not for next ???

Comment: @jon Probably because `value` is never null for city, region...?

Comment: Ok i trie to chek on get

Comment: Are you sure you've got NRE during setting value of Address property? Maybe you've got problem during getting value. You should also check for null in Address property get method

Comment: @MatSnow is probably right; if you call `value.Length` and value is null, you can't reach `Length`, hence the `NullReferenceException`. If you don't access `Length` in your other properties or if their are never null, you never get this error.

Comment: @Lazys What do you want to check within the getter? It may *never* throw an NRE, as `this`can´t be `null`.

Comment: I have to create a CSV from this class model so i test the lenght of property and i do in set ! I have to respect the lenght for every column

Comment: I confirm that i get error if check the null on get ! if i check the null on set i solve ... but i dont understand

Comment: MatSnow  i think you right!